# AWS mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu, file-upload, amazon-ec2

I am working on AWS ec2 ubuntu machine. My code is in cakephp. When I try to upload any image with crating new folder, I got following warnings.

> Warning (2): mkdir(): Permission denied
> [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line 1784]
>
> Warning (2): chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory
> [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line 1785]
>
> Warning (2):
> finfo::file(/var/www/html/app/webroot/files/user/image/35/)
> [finfo.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line 1955]
>
> Warning (2): mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied
> [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line 1784]
>
> Warning (2): chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory
> [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line 1785]
>
> Warning (2):
> move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/app/webroot/files/user/image/35/1439985339.jpg)
> [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line
> 349]
>
> Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]:
> Unable to move '/tmp/phpqvcdzp' to
> '/var/www/html/app/webroot/files/user/image/35/1439985339.jpg'
> [APP/Plugin/Upload/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php, line 349]

and code is

```
protected function _mkPath(Model $model, $field, $destDir) {
    if (!file_exists($destDir)) {
        mkdir($destDir, $this->settings[$model->alias][$field]['mode'], true);
        chmod($destDir, $this->settings[$model->alias][$field]['mode']);
    }   
    return true;
}
```

following is the plugin I am using
http://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

> should I need to give 777 permission to webroot

Comment: The user account that your webserver is running as must have appropriate permissions to create those new folders

Comment: how can I know that it has appropriate permission or not?

Comment: You check the owner/group and permissions for the folders, and you check the webserver configuration to see what user/group it's running as

Comment: should I need to give `777 permission` to `webroot`

Comment: Better to identify what group your webserver is running as, and change the folders group to match that.... then you're not opening up your security as much

Comment: we are `default vpc cloud` group.

Comment: apache2 will generally run as `www-data` in ubuntu. Use `ls -lha` to check the permission.